How to hide the picture hover text on the screen？
In Chrome, when I move my mouse over an image, tooltips appear for the ALT file description. But when I moved out, the text on my screen stayed there. This is a browser bug, I can only move to a new element with the alt attribute to override this, and then mouse out of it.
This problem has occurred several times on my Mac OS. Is there any way to solve this problem once and for all?
I hope to be able to appear next time this bug, quickly solve it.
